# It looks like both hands play the same notes (E and F), how do you play this?

Tags: technique

How do you play the E and F with each hand?  Do both hands play the same exact key?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoFFd.jpg

Comment: It must be a mistake. Does the piece have any similar passages where the hands play not in unison but (say) in octaves? Perhaps the passage you showed was meant to be like them.